# How to disable event on click on child div?

Tags: javascript, html

I making a chrome extension that adds some buttons to the website listing. That works fine before, but they did some changes in design, and now each click inside the listing element

```
 <div class="Card">
```

trigger redirects to another page except for the favorite button.

So what I need it's just to add a custom div with a small button next to that favorite button, and I did that. However, click on my button also trigger a redirect to another page.

UPD: I just realized they put div inside the anchor
like

```
<a href="detailed-page">
  <div class="card">
</a>
```

and that works next way

```
<a href="detailed-page">
  <div class="card"> <!-- click here redirect to another page -->
      <div class="favorite"> <!-- no redirect here -->
          <svg>...</svg> <!-- no redirect here -->
      </div> <!-- no redirect here -->
      <div class="custom buttons"> <!-- click here redirect to another page -->
          <svg>...</svg> <!-- click here redirect to another page -->
      </div> <!-- click here redirect to another page -->
  </div> <!-- click here redirect to another page -->
</a>
```

SOLUTION:

Ok, so solution is very simple just use **event.preventDefault()**

```
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // <<< just add this
    action();
});
```

PS. If somebody wants create an answer go ahead

Comment: You will need to provide more info for useful answers. But you might wanna check [MDN on propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: thanks, I added crucial information

Comment: @JohnDoe Did you use `e.preventDefault()` in the event handler?

Comment: Yes I did, there no click event there just following URL, but how they disable that for favorite button?

Comment: no, I need fully active buttons, they will mark object as hidden/remove mark.

Comment: I just need disable redirect when I click my button

Comment: I add a button in div, but the entire Main element inside a link. That why redirect is happens

Comment: yes I use addEventListener('click' and after event captured(i have logs) i will be redirected to detailed-page

Comment: `div` inside `a` tag is really not recommended even it works.

Comment: Joe Kdw , lol that is not my code. I making the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for something like that

```
const myLink = document.querySelector('a[href="detailed-page"]')
myLink.addEventListener('click',clickDecide)

function clickDecide(evt)
  {
  if (evt.target.matches('div.favorite, div.favorite > svg'))
     e.preventDefault();   // disable click evt
  }
```